Great Picard theorem
The great Picard Theorem is well known.
I wonder what instead can be said about the values of the function
$$
\operatorname{F}: z \mapsto \left(\operatorname{f}\left(z\right), \operatorname{f}'\left(z\right)\right) \in {\mathbb C}^{2}\quad \mbox{if}\ \operatorname{f}\ \mbox{is, say,}\ entire. 
$$
Presumably someone has already worked on that, right ?.

Well, the derivative of an entire function is entire, so apply Picard to both coordinates...  (One can also apply Liouville's theorem to get a lower bound on coverage of $\Bbb{C}^2$.)

that is of course right and shows that the image takes every value of ${\mathbb C}^2$ except maybe a set uf the form ${a} \times {\mathbb C} ; \cup ; {\mathbb C} \times {b}$ infinitely often.  But one might expect the exception-set  much smaller (maybe discrete?). Just a wild guess.

If $f$ is entire, then $F$ is holomorphic and its image is a holomorphic curve (in the affine plane). Particularly, the image is a smooth surface off the discrete (possibly empty) set of double zeros of $f$ (because $F' = (f', f'')$), and the complement of the image is dense. Is that (in effect) what you're asking?

thank you Andrew, my bad knowledge makes that I even ignored the existence of the notion of a "holomorphic curve" :(
I will read a bit, and come forward if I have new questions on that! Cheers

Where I wrote double please read triple: The image is singular at $F(z_0)$ if and only if $f'(z_0) = f''(z_0) = 0$ (which was in mind), but the order of a zero is one larger, i.e., we need to ensure $f$ is divisible by $(z-z_0)^3$ to ensure derivatives up to the second vanish.
